# Open a fragment, not in the current list of tabs, in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

I want to open a fragment, which does not lie in the list of tabs, from a fragment in an onClick() function.
I have been struggling with this for a while now. Can someone give some pointers?
All the solutions that I have seen transition from one fragment to another(both being part of the tab list).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create a instance of the fragment and use fragment Manager

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        LinkListFragment llf = new LinkListFragment();
        ft.replace(R.id.container, llf);
        ft.commit();
```

Comment: I believe your LinkListFragemnt refers to the new Fragment class that I want to replace my current fragment with, right?
And what is R.id.listFragment supposed to be?

Comment: R.id.containter is the container and LinkListFragment would be fragment you want to replace

Comment: Ok. But what is the container supposed to refer to? To the current fragment's xml id, right?

Comment: Nope , the container in your activity , where you add or replace the fragments

Comment: So I believe this container should be the id of the ViewPager container since I have implemented the tabs that way. Am I right?